# Comparing data sets in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been reading over the docs and I'm having trouble understanding searching/filtering.

For instance. (example) I have 2 data sets almost identical

```
['Item': 'blah1', 'periodDate': date1, .........
'Item': 'blah2', 'periodDate': date1, ......... 
'Item': 'blah3', 'periodDate': date1, .........
'Item': 'blah4', 'periodDate': date1, .........]
```

and data set2

```
['Item': 'blah1', 'periodDate': date2, .........
'Item': 'blah2', 'periodDate': date2, ......... 
'Item': 'blah3', 'periodDate': date2, .........
'Item': 'blah5', 'periodDate': date2, .........]
```

I'm trying to compare data sets to output items that are in data set 1  but not 2 and items that are in set 2 but not 1 so in this case

`'Item': 'blah4', 'periodDate': date1` and `'Item': 'blah5', 'periodDate': date2,`

this is something I could do in PSQL but I'm new to elastic so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that you can't do that directly through elasticsearch DSL. You could use scroll (read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-scroll.html) to read through both data sets in a script and compare it manually.

Don't think there's anything else that you can get elastic to do for you.